# Using WireShark - Edit packets and send them over the web again

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I want to intercept packets I send over the internet and edit them. I have got the hang of packet sniffing and finding traffic on the network. I'm playing a game on my phone where you can watch ads to earn coins, and I'm wondering, since I can find the request to the server to give me more coins using wireshark, can I send those packets myself so I can get more coins?

I'd also be interested in experimenting with this for other utilities. I'm using Windows and I know VB.net and some C#. If anyone could help me to find a tool, or code to send my own packets, of data, then I'd be very grateful.

For all I know, this may be impossible, but I'd love to learn more about this :) Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in this - wireshark is not the tool to use. Create your own proxy server on your machine and direct your phone's traffic through it. Then you can monitor the packets sent on the server, and resend ones to earn coins etc.